# Intellij Idea Fires "Cannot find declaration to go to" In .xhtml Files

Tags: intellij-idea, xhtml

I am working on a Maven project and using Intellij Idea ide to develop it. I used Idea on 4-5 different computers and there wasn't any error for finding usages. Recenlty, I had to change my laptop. After installing Idea and opening projects, *finding usages* feature didn't work on .xhtml files.

I searced for almost every solutions wrote on Internet but all of them were for .java files. There is no problem at any other file types in my project. Also, I can go to java classes and methods from .xhtml files and from java classes/methods to .xhtml files at my other computers.

I also couldn't find any solution on Intellij settings of my other computers so, I need a solution here.

An example for my problem as below:

[image]

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart` If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide a minimal reproducible project sample

Comment: I tried it several times with other aforementioned solutions, but it didn't solve my issue. I will do what you suggested and update situation here if any good result comes.